# why does image rendring through ghostscript API takes so much time?

Tags: java, ghostscript

Im using Ghostscript to render images from PDFs through  java using commands,  however I’m trying to run Ghoscript for image rendering from PDF using ghost4j-0.5.0.jar  with the below code that I took it from [this](http://www.ghost4j.org/highlevelapisamples.html) website.

The problem is that the rending process takes more than two minutes to generate one image, though it takes a second to do it through command line, the thing is im trying to run every thing through java, I want to stop using imagemagick and ghostscript as a tools, please note that im satisfied with using ghoscript and i don't want to use any other tool as it provides me with the image quality and sizes i need,
the code im using is,:

```
    public class SimpleRendererExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    imageRenderingFromPdf();
}

public static void imageRenderingFromPdf() {

    try {

         PDFConverter converter = new PDFConverter();
         PDFDocument doc;
        // load PDF document
        PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
        document.load(new File("d:/cur/outputfile.pdf"));
        // create renderer
        SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();
        // set resolution (in DPI)
        renderer.setResolution(100);
        System.out.println("started");
        // render
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Image> images = renderer.render(document);
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("reder " + (after - before) / 1000);
        // write images to files to disk as PNG
        try {
            before = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) images.get(0), "png", new File(
                    "d:/dd" + ".png"));
            after = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("write " + (after - before) / 1000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things what's slowing down the 'rendering' process.

First of all, it's not due Ghostscript, Ghostscript by it's self works a same and it doesn't matter if it's executed via command line or API.

The speed difference is the result of ghost4j rendering implementation. I just checked the source code of the ghost4j and I see that it's a mixture of the iText and Ghostscript implementation.

So, how the code that you use works:

1. First the pdf document is loaded and parsed by iText.
2. Then a copy of the complete document is made by writing loaded pdf document back to disk to a new place.
3. Then Ghostscript is initialized.
4. Then Ghostscript loads, parse and render the document from a new place for a second time.
5. For each page, Ghostscript is calling ghost4j display device callback.
6. For each display device callback, ghost4j takes rasterized page from the memory and stores it to the disk.
7. The end.

Week parts are iText and used display device callback. I thing that the speed could be gained by letting Ghostscript take care of the rasterized result storage instead of doing it manually from the Java...

I think now you can see why you noticed the speed difference.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but can you please explain this sentence to me ?
"letting Ghostscript take care of the rasterized result storage instead of doing it manually from the Java"

Comment: Yep, what i want to say is to simply call Ghostscript.initialize(String[] args) where args would be your command line parameters.

Comment: ok you've answered my question:)  but as per this [link](http://www.ghost4j.org/coreapisamples.html) it converts it to input.ps first then it display callback, why do you think it does that?

Comment: The samples from your link are actually two separate samples. First one shows how to convert input.ps to output.pdf by letting Ghostscript take care of saving the output file to the disk. Second one shows how to rasterize postscript file to the memory and nothing else. Rasterized page image from the second sample needs to be handled by your own, as the sample shows that it's taking care about storing rasterized page to the disk by using ImageIO.write().